# Postman - extracting value from HTML description list

Tags: javascript, html, postman, cheerio

I've searched for a while trying to find a way in Postman to extract a HTML description list value from the response body where the description list contains multiple values.

Example of response body:

```
<dl>
                    <dd>Fruit</dd>
                    <dt>Apple</dt>

                    <dd>Vegetable</dd>
                    <dt>Carrot</dt>
</dl>
```

How do I just get just the Vegetable value? I've tried using the following

```
const $ = cheerio.load(pm.response.text())
console.log('Vegetable', $('dt').text())
```

This then returns both values

```
"Vegetable" "AppleCarrot"
```

The Fruit & Vegetable values will change once the request is rerun, this means I'm unable to go just based off their names.

I'm probably over thinking this, thanks in advance.

Comment: what are the conditions to acquire the Vegetable? Based on content or based on order?
I think in jQuery you can do $('dt').first().text() or something

Comment: That worked! Thank you for such a quick response.

Comment: If the order is always consistent I think you can `var vegetable = $('dd:contains("Vegetable")').next().text();`

Answer (score 1):

EricG posted the following above.

JQuery allows you to filter based off order using the following:

```
const $ = cheerio.load(pm.response.text())
console.log('Vegetable', $('dt').first().text())
```

Alternatively to the above if you need to go further down the list you can use:

```
const $ = cheerio.load(pm.response.text())
console.log('Vegetable', $('dt').eq(0).text())
```

Changing the value in .eq(#) starting from 0 will then following the items down the list.